# Evitar que al sobreponer un elemento semitransparente sobre otro se vuelva más opaco

Tags: html, css, diseño

He estado intentado algo pero no encuentro la solución, la más fácil (según yo, es recurrir a svg)

Aquí va el código:

Tengo estos elementos, los cuales son transparentes de este modo:

```css
.c
{
    position:relative;
}
.s{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    position:absolute;
}
.b
{
    left:25px;
    top:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
    <div class="s a">
    </div>
    <div class="s b">
    </div>
</div>
```

Pero lo que sucede es que se hace más oscuro en el área que se sobreponen.

Comment: Gracias por editar mi pregunta, soy nuevo aún espero que entiendas